# QGIS2web Ordnance Survey Map (raster layer) shifted against the QGIS project

Tags: qgis, raster, qgis2web, ordnance-survey

I am wondering, why the QGIS2web can't accept the Ordnance Survey map location in the interactive version.

The Ordnance Survey map is set at EPSG 27700 British National Grid sor does a whole QGIS project and other layers too.

Other layers come the same as they're visible in QGIS, unlike the Ordnance Survey map canvas, which is the raster one. This one is shifted a bit and remains the loanword of EPSG 3857 Pseudo-Mercator coordinate system, want I can see when entering the code in layers.js.

```
       var lyr_Area6_1 = new ol.layer.Image({
                        opacity: 1,
                        title: "Area6",
                        
                        
                        source: new ol.source.ImageStatic({
                           url: "./layers/Area6_1.png",
                  attributions: ' ',
                            projection: 'EPSG:3857',
                            alwaysInRange: true,
                            imageExtent: [-23488.879733, 6814799.233467, 
                -22713.936608, 6815622.095812]
                        })
                    });


      How can I fix it?
```

[image]

**UPDATE:**

In the QGIS2web plugin, there is an option: Match project CRS. When I tick it, then my map is much more shifted than previously:

[image]

I tried to use the coordinate capture and set these coordinates manually, but without result, unfortunately. Is there any way to fix it?

Again, both project as well as my OS raster map and the layers are in EPSG: 27700 British National Grid format.

Comment: can you explain what the picture is showing? what should it look like? where are the layers coming from>

Comment: The layers are vector ones and map is the raster layer. As you can see in the image above. They are a bit shifted.

Comment: please use the [edit] link to update your question to make it clearer

Comment: @IanTurton question updated. This is the problem I am facing now.

Comment: @MKR - it seems to be extremely difficult to help you with only such description and without data sharing. I've created a project in EPSG: 27700, added raster and vectorized a few features on it for a control, exported to OpenLayers format and there is absolutely no shift (option Match project CRS on and off). Apart from having features in EPSG:27700 I've reprojected both raster and vector to EPSG:3857 and EPSG:4326 (WGS-84) and all of them were perfectly coincident in both QGIS and OpenLayers output. I doubt that there is something extraordinary about OS raster maps. QGIS 3.14, qgis2web3.16

Comment: @MKR - and which version of QGIS and plugin do you use?

Comment: It's sad to read this. I have 3.12. What description would you like? I can upload some stuff for you if you are able to help.
Thanks & Regards,

Comment: @MKR, it would be great if you can share the data. However, if your data is confidential, maybe you could just follow my path? Take any raster (e.g. orthoimage), reproject it to EPSG:27700, vectorize a few features on it also in EPSG:27700, use qgis2web and see if there is a shift?